# Equivalent Definition of the Closure of a Set

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove the following Lemma:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $B\subseteq X$ be a subset. Then holds

$$\overline{B}=\bigcap_{X\setminus A\in\tau \atop B\subseteq A}A.$$

I have $\overline{\overline{A}}=\overline{A}$ and my definition of $\overline{A}$ is the union of boundary points.

Comment: This will give $\overline{B} = X$. Did you mean intersection?

Comment: well, sure I mean intersection. It looks like I write bigcup instead bigcap, my fail.

Comment: I want to say the closure of $B$ is the smallest closed set which contains $B$

Comment: Not every problem involving sets is a problem in set theory.

Comment: What's your definition of boundary points ? I guess $x \in \partial B \iff \forall U \in \tau: x \in U \Rightarrow U \cap B \neq \emptyset$ ? Where $\partial B$ is the set of what we will call boundary points.

Comment: My definition of a boundaey point is: Let $B\subseteq X$ a subset. A point $x\in X$ is called boundary point of $B$, if and only if every environment of $x$ contains at least one point of $B$. So I would agree with you André. Certainly I use $\partial$ to express that I mean the border of $B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call a *boundary point* is rather called an *adherence point*, while a boundary point is a point in the boundary $\partial A$, i.e. a point whose every neighborhood contains both point from $A$ and points not in $A.$

First you should prove that $\overline A$ is a closed set, i.e. $X\setminus\overline A\in\tau$. But if $x\in X\setminus\overline A$, then $x$ is not an adherence point, so there is a neighborhood not intersecting $A$. That means $X\setminus\overline A$ is a neighborhood of each of its elements and thus an open set.

So $\overline A$ is closed and must contains the intersection of all closed supersets of $A$. This gives one inclusion.

For the other inclusion, show that $\overline A$ is a subset of each closed superset $C$. To this end, take a point $x\notin C$ and show that it is not an adherence point.

Comment: Thank for the information, I used leo.org which used the same word for "Berührpunkt" (what I mean) and for "Randpunkt" (what I write) ... That's complicate. Your arguments I also used for the Lemma that $\overline{A}$ is a closed set. This was more or less easy for me, but the last two parts of your answer... I don't know why I didn't see it. Thank you very much!